# Macos resets screen refresh rate after disconnect

Tags: display, screen

I have 4 external monitors (non-mac) with MacBoook 16". 2 of them (C27JG5x and Optix G24C support 144GhZ.) I have a few issues with that.

- Apple **Displays** settings doesn't have an option to change the refresh rate.

[image: Screenshot of the Displays system preference pane]

- I found an external program [Display Menu](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/display-menu/id549083868) that can do it.

[image: Screenshot of the program Display Menu showing display resolutions]

Unfortunately, each time I unplug displays (or **Reboot**/put my Mac to sleep) the Refresh Rate setting resets to 60Ghz, however, macOS stills remember the **Display arrangement** and their resolutions.

Is there any way that Macbook would use the previous refresh rate settings as well?

Comment: have you checked with NVRAM Reset?

Comment: Yes, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Scaled, but hold down the Option key when you click on it. You'll get a list of supported resolutions.  If you find your Monitors do this often, try using an [EDID emulator](https://a.co/d/4sCoQph) on your external monitors.  (note: non-affiliate link)

Comment: I just resolved this issue. I switched back to archlinux :)

Comment: While changing to scaled does allow setting the refresh rate, after sleep or restart the refresh rate is reverted the default and away from any custom setting (e.g., reset from 60Ghz back to Variable Refresh Rate)